# Adjusting SELECT statement based on availability of form data

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, where-clause

I have a `books` table with the following columns `bid, isbn, title, author, year`

In a search page the user is provided with 3 optional inputs: `title`, `author` and `isbn`, and the app searches the database for books having title like `title` or author like `author` or isbn equals to `isbn`. And any of the three inputs can be empty.

And this is the SQL query I'm using:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    title = form.title.data or 'NONE'
    author = form.author.data or 'NONE'
    isbn = form.isbn.data or ''
    books = db.execute('SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE (:title) OR author LIKE (:author) or isbn=(:isbn)',
                        {
                            'title': f'%{title}%',
                            'author':f'%{author}%',
                            'isbn': isbn
                        }).fetchall()
```

The `or 'NONE'` parts are a workaround to avoid having SQL query with `LIKE '%%'` since it will fetch all the table rows, and I know that there are no `NONE` entries in my books table.

However, this is a dirty workaround and I don't like it (also slower?). So, what's a clean way to perform the query having empty variables in a LIKE operator.

Note: I'm avoiding ORM deliberately.

Comment: why not dynamically build your where statement based on the input

Comment: @Chris please elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could explicitly avoid `'%%'` in the pattern matchings, like

```
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE 
    (:title <> '%%' AND title LIKE :title)
    OR (:author <> '%%' AND author LIKE :author) 
    OR isbn = :isbn
```

Comment: Suppose the user has only provided an `isbn` number = `0061150142`, now the query is: `SELECT * FROM books WHERE (title <> '%%' AND title LIKE '%%') OR (author <> '%%' AND author LIKE '%%')  OR isbn = '0061150142'` which also will fetch ALL rows.

Comment: @Algo, no, it's `SELECT * FROM books WHERE ('%%' <> '%%' AND title LIKE '%%') OR ('%%' <> '%%' AND author LIKE '%%') OR isbn = '0061150142'`